# alsa: How to programmatically find if a device is busy/in use using it name and without opening it

Tags: linux, resources, device, alsa

We have a Linux device which has a speaker and MIC devices. These devices are shared among different modules - example a VOIP call can use speaker, a hazard Warning system can use speaker, a Voice prompt can use a speaker etc:

There seems to be a function in ALSA which uses pcm to provide the status. 
int snd_pcm_status (snd_pcm_t *     pcm, snd_pcm_status_t *     status)

However the *pcm is returned by snd_pcm_open. We do not want to open the device as we would like to know the status of the device using its "name"

Alsa API is [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html)

How can we check if a resource/device is busy without opening it and using its name?

Answer (score 2):

The same information for playback stream X of device Y on card Z is available in the file `/proc/asound/cardZ/pcmYp/subX/status`; when the device is not open, it just says "closed".

Please note that you cannot use this information to decide if you can open the device, because some other process could have openend it just after you've read this information. The only way to check if you can open it is to actually try.

Answer (score 0):

Though it requires /dev/dsp, this seems to work:

```
#!/bin/dash

## If the speaker is not used by any, returns 0, and prints "free"
## Otherwise, returns 1 and prints "not free"

iExit (){
    trap '' 0
    exit $1
}

iCatch (){
    # The speaker is already in use
    echo not free
    iExit 1
}

trap iCatch 0

{
    exec 3>&1 1>/dev/dsp
    # If the execution reaches here, the speaker is not used by any
    # Otherwise, it's catched by iCatch
    exec 1>&3
    echo free
    iExit 0
} 2>/dev/null
```

Without PulseAudio, it seems on some PC only one output is accepted at one time; on others simultaneous playbacks are allowed. But even in the latter case, the above code works.

**NB**: The above code does **not** work with bash; for bash, simply use if/else rather than trap.

**NB 2**: /dev/dsp may be lacking depending on the kernel configuration.